# Multiple GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY generations

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm trying to create multiple texture 2D arrays for texturing a heightmap along with a bumpmap for the textures.

The problem is when I load multiple arrays it overwrites the first array's texture data.

```
#include "TextureArray.h"
#include "Debug.h"

TextureArray::TextureArray(const char* directory, int number)
{
    initBuffers();

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        sprintf(buffer, "%s%i.png", directory, i);

        if(!this->LoadFile(buffer, number, i, &width, &height))
        {
            Destroy();
            return;
        }
    }
}

void TextureArray::initBuffers()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &textures);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textures);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
}

void TextureArray::Destroy()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textures);
}

bool TextureArray::LoadFile(char* file, int size, int index, int* width, int* height)
{
    Texture* texture = LoadTextureFromFile(file, false);

    if(texture == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    unsigned char* data = texture->data;

    if(data)
    {
        if(index == 0)
        {
            *width = texture->width;
            *height = texture->height;

            glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, texture->bitDepth == ImageType::RGBA ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, *width, *height, size, 0, texture->bitDepth == ImageType::RGBA ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
            checkError("I==0");
        }

        if(texture->width != *width || texture->height != *height)
        {
            return false;
        }

        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, index, texture->width,  texture->height, 1, texture->bitDepth == ImageType::RGBA ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        checkError(file);

        free(data);
    }

    free(texture);

    return true;
}
```

Here are the calls to this code:

```
textureArray = new TextureArray("textures/", "bumpmaps/", TEXTURE_ARRAY_SIZE);
//bumpMapArray = new TextureArray("bumpmaps/", TEXTURE_ARRAY_SIZE);
```

Comment: I'm confused - your constructor only takes a single string and a number of files to load, but your call to the constructor takes 2 strings and the `TEXTURE_ARRAY_SIZE`. Is there another constructor than what you've posted above? If so, please include it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textures);
```

which is wring since the correct binding target for array textures is `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` (which you correctly when setting the parameters and specified the data). Actually, your code is just working with the default texure object (named 0, and archaic leftover from the days of GL 1.0 when there were no texture objects at all), which is by default bound to the texture array target of all texture units. The texture object you have created and bound as a 3D texture was never really used.

Comment: Yes, inside TextureArray::initBuffers().

Comment: @martyj: what is this comment supposed to tell me?